# How to remove all numbers from a list in Lisp

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp, nested-lists

I am learning Lisp and have a problem where I have to remove all the numbers from a list, which also has nested lists. For example:

```
(REMOVE-NUM '(2 A (3 B) C D))
```

will output:

```
(A (B) C D)
```

I am **not** allowed to use `loop`, `if`, or `mapcan`. I am to use basic operators and `cond` statements. This is my current code:

```
(defun REMOVE-NUM (L)
  (cond
   ((null L) nil)

   ((numberp (car L)) (REMOVE-NUM (cdr L)))

   (t (cons (car L) (REMOVE-NUM (cdr L))))   
)
```

My current code can remove the numeric atoms without nested lists, but once nested lists are involved, it lists out the nested list, without actually processing it. I know that this is an issue with my logic behind the recursion, but I for some reason cannot see it. My instinct is to change the last line to:

```
(t (cons (REMOVE-NUM (car  L) (REMOVE-NUM (cdr L))))
```

another recursive call in the last line, but doing so gives an error because it tries to take car of an atom and pass it as a list to my function which can only take lists. I thought of maybe changing the base cases, but I can't think of a way to do so since numberp has to be condition used. Where is my recursion going wrong/what is it missing?

Comment: Should it also work for `cons` pairs? (For example, `(remove-num '((A . 1) (B . 2)))`)

Comment: Your function `REMOVE-NUM` lacks a closing parenthesis.

Comment: @MartinPůda The prompt doesn't say anything about ```cons``` pairs. It specifies that the function will only be receiving a list of atoms, and or nested lists with atoms.

Comment: @Kaz It's probably more that the professor wants the students to learn the low-level list architecture before they are allowed to use higher-order functions which effectively hide this implementation layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it obvious? Separate `atom` (which could be unified with the `null` case actually) and the `listp` (which could then be simply `t`) cases. You'll need to accept that your input isn't necessarily a list if you want recursion all the way, or else you need to peek at the `cdr` and make sure it's `listp` before you recurse. Throw in a `cons` or two in your test case.

> (REMOVE-NUM '(2 A (3 B) C (D . 7) (8 . E) F))

If you don't need to handle `cons` cells in your lists, simply

```
(defun REMOVE-NUM (L)
  (cond
   ((atom L) L)
   ((numberp (car L)) (REMOVE-NUM (cdr L)))
   (t (cons (REMOVE-NUM (car L))
            (REMOVE-NUM (cdr L)) ))))
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/evidN7

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am a bit confused; are you saying to rewrite the function with ```atomp``` and ```listp```? The prompt does say the function will only ever take lists as input and that I must use recursion all the way.

Comment: But when you recurse, you don't know whether the `cdr` is a list.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've gone to office hours and had this clarified. My professor's response was slightly different as it involved using ```numberp``` twice, once on ```car L``` and once on ```L```. Your solution is much easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

The OP code is working for lists which contain atoms, but not for lists which also contain more lists of atoms.

Consider the case: `(remove-number '((a 1 2) b 3))`. OP code checks:

- Is the input an empty list? No.
- Is the first element of the input a number? No.
- Ok then, keep the first element of the input and continue.

But OP code fails to check for the important case: is the first element of the input itself a list?

OP has an instinct to change the final line to: `(t (cons (REMOVE-NUM (car  L) (REMOVE-NUM (cdr L))))`. This is an idea in the right direction, but it will not be effective because the code is not checking whether the first element of `L` is a list.

Instead, code should check:

- Is the input an empty list? If yes, just return an empty list.
- Is the first element of the input a list? If yes, cons the result of removing numbers from this sublist onto the result of removing numbers from the remaining input list and return the result.
- Is the first element of the input a number? If yes, just remove the numbers from the remaining input list and return the result.
- Finally, the first element is not a list and it is not a number, so cons the first element onto the result of removing the numbers from the remaining input list.

That is to say: as the function processes elements of the input list it must be able to distinguish among and handle elements that are lists, elements that are numbers, and elements that are something else.

Below is one implementation of this function, but it would be good for OP to try to write this for themselves first after reading the above. There are of course other ways that this could be written. This implementation does not seem to meet OP requirements in that it uses `if` instead of `cond`, and it is unclear what *"basic operators"* are allowed. In any case, it is relatively straightforward to write something like this using, e.g, `cond`, `atom`, and `and` while avoiding `let` if it would help OP to meet requirements.

```lisp
(defun remove-numbers (xss)
  (if (null xss) '()
      (let ((x (car xss))
            (remainder (cdr xss)))
        (if (listp x)
            (cons (remove-numbers x) (remove-numbers remainder))
            (if (numberp x)
                (remove-numbers remainder)
                (cons x (remove-numbers remainder)))))))
```

```
CL-USER> (remove-numbers '(2 a (3 b) c d))
(A (B) C D)
CL-USER> (remove-numbers '(1 a ((2 3 b c) d 4) 5 6))
(A ((B C) D))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I unfortunately am not allowed to use ```if```. I will try to translate this into what am allowed to use.

Comment: @WilliamYoung -- I was just adding some comments about that. It should be pretty straightforward to take the basic ideas and develop a solution using whatever requirements you have.

Answer (score 1):

Your code (modulo formatting and some missing close parens at the end) is almost correct, but missing a case.  Here is pseudocode which includes that case as well as another case to catch errors

To remove numbers from a possibly nested list, *l*:

- is *l* not a list at all?  this is an error;
- is *l* the empty list?  if it is the result is the empty list;
- is the car of *l* a list?  if it is then the result is a list made by consing the result of removing numbers from the car of *l* onto the result of removing numbers from the cdr of *l*;
- is the car of *l* a number?  if it is the result is the result of removing numbers from the cdr of *l*;
- otherwise the result is the result of consing the car of *l* onto the result of removing the numbers from the cdr of *l*.

For the first case, the '*l* is not a list' case, you can signal an error with `(error "...")`.  If your instructor says you are not allowed to check errors in the arguments to your function like this have *strong* words with them.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define
  (remove-num ls)
  (cond  
    ((null? ls) '())
    ((list? (car ls))
      (cons (remove-num (car ls)) (remove-num (cdr ls)))
    )
    ((number? (car ls)) (remove-num (cdr ls)))
    (else (cons (car ls) (remove-num (cdr ls))))
  )
)
(remove-num '(2 A (B 3) C D))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**